# Filter document which the object in the array matches the condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have such docs which have an array of objects/dictionaries which each object contains `records.saleStatus`, `records.price.firstprice`, and  `records.price.secondPrice`.

If `saleStatus == "Sold"` then the `price` value is not falsy, it means that `firstprice` or `secondPrice` has some values, not both null or zero.

I want such docs which

```
records.saleStatus == "Sold" && (price.firstPrice == 0 || null) &&  (price.secondPrice == 0 || null)
```

Input document:

```
[
    {
        "title": "potato",
        "records": [
            {
                "saleStatus": "Sold",
                "price": {
                    "firstprice": 100,
                    "secondPrice": 150
                }, 
            },
            {
                "saleStatus": "Unsold",
                "price": {
                    "firstprice": 100,
                    "secondPrice": 150
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "title": "tomato",
        "records": [
            {
                "saleStatus": "Sold",
                "price": {
                    "firstprice": null,
                    "secondPrice": 0
                }, 
            },
            {
                "saleStatus": "Sold",
                "price": {
                    "firstprice": 80,
                    "secondPrice": 150
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "corn",
        "records": [
            {
                "saleStatus": "Sold",
                "price": {
                    "firstprice": null,
                    "secondPrice": null
                }, 
            },
            {
                "saleStatus": "Sold",
                "price": {
                    "firstprice": 80,
                    "secondPrice": 150
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "ginger",
        "records": [
            {
                "saleStatus": "Unsold",
                "price": {
                    "firstprice": null,
                    "secondPrice": null
                }, 
            },
            {
                "saleStatus": "Sold",
                "price": {
                    "firstprice": 80,
                    "secondPrice": null,
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
        "title": "tomato",
        "records": [
            {
                "saleStatus": "Sold",
                "price": {
                    "firstprice": null,
                    "secondPrice": 0
                }, 
            },
            {
                "saleStatus": "Sold",
                "price": {
                    "firstprice": 80,
                    "secondPrice": 150
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "corn",
        "records": [
            {
                "saleStatus": "Sold",
                "price": {
                    "firstprice": null,
                    "secondPrice": null
                }, 
            },
            {
                "saleStatus": "Sold",
                "price": {
                    "firstprice": 80,
                    "secondPrice": 150
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$match` stage with `$elemMatch` to filter the document(s) with the object that fulfills all the match conditions in the `records` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      records: {
        $elemMatch: {
          "saleStatus": "Sold",
          "price.firstprice": {
            $in: [
              0,
              null
            ]
          },
          "price.secondPrice": {
            $in: [
              0,
              null
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo `.aggregate()` @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BZGcqrhdPV8)

---

For `.find()` query,

```
db.collection.find({
  records: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "saleStatus": "Sold",
      "price.firstprice": {
        $in: [
          0,
          null
        ]
      },
      "price.secondPrice": {
        $in: [
          0,
          null
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo `.find()` @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E5Rn4E6a7iD)